# Algorithms for mulit armed bandit problems

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

[Algorithms for multi armed bandit problems](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260367055_Algorithms_for_multi-armed_bandit_problems)
can some one explain what are the x and y axis for the graphs in the research paper"algorithms for multi armed bandits" in page no: 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Figure 1 on the linked paper (this is on page 11):

- The quantity on the y-axis for every subfigure is described in the caption below the subfigure. For subfigures (a), (c), and (e), this is the *Regret per turn*. For subfigures (b), (d), and (f), this is the *Percentage of optimal arm plays*.
- The quantity on the x-axis is simply a measure of time / turn counter / timestep. All the way to the left we have results for the very beginning of an experiment (when we start learning), all the way to the right we have results for the end of an experiment (when we have had a lot of previous steps to learn from).